# Is "to do well" used more frequently in India?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, subcontinental-english

When I talk to Indians on line, I have the impression that they use the expression (compound verb?) "to do well" a lot. Is it only an impression of mine, or is that expression more frequently used in India?

EDITION:

Apparently, the Indians I have read or talked to use it to mean "to be successful", "to grow economically", *vel simila*. Examples:

**Indian shuttlers will do well at Rio**
http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/badminton/Indian-shuttlers-will-do-well-at-Rio-Prakash-Padukone/articleshow/49661452.cms

**Will ISL and HIL help India do well internationally**
http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/sports/will-isl-and-hil-help-india-do-well-internationally/articleshow/49170068.cms

**Indian market doing well, reflects fundamentals of cos, not economy: Adrian Mowat, JP Morgan**
http://articles.economictimes.indiatimes.com/2014-03-20/news/48402221_1_adrian-mowat-em-growth-indian-equities

Usually, I don't hear or read other English speakers besides Indians using that expression. I am not a native anglophone and don't have any idea if that is an idiomatic expression in the whole anglosphere (where I have been in person only during 3 or 4 days when visiting London).

Naturally, with "more frequently", I mean "more frequently than in other places".

Comment: You need to include full context. Otherwise, your question is too broad or primarily-opinion-based. Please edit your question.

Comment: Can you give a sentence where this is used?

Comment: There are expressions in US English along the lines of "To do something well is it's own reward."

Comment: More frequently than where?  It's possible that it's used more frequently in India than in some places, but more frequently in other places than in India.

Comment: Is the Kolhapur Corpus available online anywhere? That might be a starting point.

Comment: I just edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: @choster: Having just spent a couple of minutes searching, I get the impression that one might be a lost cause (I hit an awful lot of dead links). [This page](http://clu.uni.no/icame/manuals/KOLHAPUR/INDEX.HTM) points out that when they were putting that corpus together (in 1978) there simply weren't enough IE "imaginative prose" (fiction?) source texts to make meaningful comparisons with AmE or BrE.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro Can you give a full sentence _here_ in your question? Don't make us search for it, make it easy for us to answer your question.

Comment: @Mitch
I can't remember exactly how the expression was used in conversations because I don't know if I had understood its meaning properly, but I remember something like "southern Indian states are doing well". Regarding the links, the sentences are in the links and in the titles themselves, `Indian shuttlers will do well at Rio: Prakash Padukone`, `Will ISL and HIL help India do well internationally?` and `Will ISL and HIL help India do well internationally?`, but I really thought those sentences wouldn't be sufficient, so I linked the sites for you to know what they are talking about.

Comment: Oops, I wrote a title twice. The third one was `Indian market doing well, reflects fundamentals of cos, not economy: Adrian Mowat, JP Morgan`.

Comment: The two answer agree in most things but apparently disagree on whether the expression is more common in India than in other places. Also, one of them says that the expression could sound odd or have different meaning to non Indians. I'm going to wait a little more before choosing one of the answers.

Comment: Per your added examples, that usage of "do well" is common in the US among native, non-Indian speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Personal thoughts

As a native Brit, "to do well" sounds perfectly normal to my ear; I suggest it is a generic English phrase, rather than a particularly Indian-English phrase.

### Research

- Random example of the phrase, from an [education website](http://montessorimadmen.com/blog/2012/7/13/is-your-child-really-doing-well.html), whose contributors appear to be based in the USA:

> Her child is in a local public school and without prompting from me she added “he’s doing well” to the end of her statement.

- [Thesaurus entries for "do well"](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/do%20well), especially under the tab "prosper" sound perfectly natural equivalents to me:

> prosper, bloom, flourish, thrive

- Its usage from google ngrams compares favourably to these synonyms based on the [American English corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20well%2Cprosper%2Cflourish%2C%20bloom%2C%20thrive&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20well%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprosper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflourish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbloom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrive%3B%2Cc0) and the [British English corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20well%2Cprosper%2Cflourish%2Cbloom%2Cthrive&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20well%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprosper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflourish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbloom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrive%3B%2Cc0).
- Googling ["team doing well"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22team+doing+well%22) brings up plenty of results; none on the first page seem to be from India.

### Conclusion

My personal thoughts are borne out by evidence: **"to do well"** is a generic English phrase, rather than a particularly Indian-English phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Some fervent discussions in the comment thread. Interesting to read!

To answer your question - YES, ***To do well*** is a commonly used phrase in InE.  It is associated mostly with performance (like performance in sports, performance of stock markets, performance in academics and the likes, as you have referred in your examples). However, it might be an Indianism which sounds odd to native speakers(where to do well means something entirely different). For instance, there are quite a number of Books to crack competitive exams and interviews that are titled

- How to do well in CAT
- How to do well in GMAT
- How to do well in Job Interviews

etc. in the Indian Book Stores. Implying, how to score higher grades or how to crack job interviews, performing well.

Here's a [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+do+well&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20do%20well%3B%2Cc0) for "to do well" which shows that it is a regularly used term

In my personal view, searching in google(in domains like CA, AU, DE apart from IN) with the term "How to do well" fetches a lot of relevant results, indicating that the phrase might be an acceptable usage in other geographies as well.